# Once i create and use own module then it will gives error like: Unable to resolve module

Tags: react-native, npm

I am new in react-native and I have, for the first time, created my own module(npm).

I have tried to create my own module(npm) for common components and individually it works fine. However once I install, link it in our app, and try to use those components, it gives an error like this:

```
 Unable to resolve module `<Module-name>` from `<file>`: Module `<Module-name>` does not exist in the Haste module map.
```

(Note: I have tested using Android Emulator only)

I have followed the below steps for module and test app creation

**For Module**

1. `react-native init <module-name>`
2. Add simple code of component in main `index.js`
3. And set pacakge.json like this:

   ```json
   {
     "name": "<module-name>",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "private": true,
     "main": "index.js",
     "scripts": {
       "start": "react-native start",
       "test": "jest",
       "lint": "eslint .",
       "build": "echo 'build script executed'"
     },
     "dependencies": {
       "react": "16.8.6",
       "react-native": "0.60.4"
     },
   ```

Now I check this component (react-native run-android), it will work fine.

Now I have tried to use in an app with the below steps

**For Test App**

1. Create new fresh app (`react-native init <app-name>`)
2. Install created npm with full path like;

   ```
   npm install <full path of component>
   ```
3. Now I try `react-native link <full path of component>`, I have also tried simple `react-native link`, but nothing happens.
4. Now I run app using `react-native run-android`, however every time it gives the same error like;

   ```
   Unable to resolve module <created-module name>
   ```

test app `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "<app-name>",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.4",
    "react-native-my-library": "^1.0.2",
    "<created-module-name>": "file:../<created-module-name>"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "eslint": "6.1.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Created module successfully installed but I think it is not linked properly and it will gives error.

So what is wrong here ?

Please give me suggestion / help.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your module has android&ios folders? Most of the time `react-native link` does not work for native libraries. You have to do it yourself.

Comment: @firats Module for both android & ios, actually it is not specific android & ios, i have also try react-native link <full path module> but nothing to change in android like gradlefile, setting.gradle etc..

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your module is successfully published in npm repository. Otherwise you can not use `npm install <full path of component>`.

If you are using

`npm install <full path of component>`

command for installing your module to a Test App from npm repo. Specify in your package.json like

```
"<created-module-name>": "file:../<created-module-name>"
```

is **wrong**. You need to **remove** that line from your package.json and try to install like;

```
npm install --save <full path of component>
```

This will automatically create a line in your package.json. You can now manually link your module.

For manual linking you can follow that [guide](https://engineering.brigad.co/demystifying-react-native-modules-linking-964399ec731b).

Edited:

If you are using in your local computer,

Then no need to `npm install`.

Just copy your module into your project `node_modules` folder.
Then in you package.json add;

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "your_module_name": "your_module_version"
   ...
}
```

Then, you just follow the manual linking process that I mentioned above.

Comment: I don't have published my module, i have just used in my local PC.
 about package.json, this line "<created-module-name>": "file:../<created-module-name>"  automatically created.

Comment: As per you answer, i follow a steps then resolve error of "Unable to resolve module". But still i am facing one issue once i use component in test app, please check below screen shot:

Error:
https://prnt.sc/ok85mu

Module package,json
https://prnt.sc/ok8528

Created simpale text Component App.js
https://prnt.sc/ok84t0

Test app package.json
https://prnt.sc/ok84gv

Use of crated component App.js
https://prnt.sc/ok846a

@firats

Comment: As I can see from your screenshots, you created a new project instead of a library for your component and then you tried to import it into your main project. This is a wrong approach. You just cant import a react-native project into an another one. You should create a react-native-library to do that. Remove your module from your project, then you can create new library with this way, [react-native-create-library](https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library). After that follow my answer once again.

Comment: Okey, Let me try. @firats

Comment: Don't forget to delete android&ios folders from library after create it. Because you just want to use only a jsx text component.

Comment: As per your suggestion, i have create library and remove android& ios folder but my question is where to write my own component code ? please check structure
https://prnt.sc/ok9vz7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197032/discussion-between-vishal-gadhiya-and-firats).

Comment: A long time ago, i have successfully create library and link in my test app but, once i try to use this library component then give the error like https://prnt.sc/omtosp
So my question is how can i use my library component, please check below usage
https://prnt.sc/omtpkp

Comment: The first screenshot shows there is something wrong with your linking. Try `import TestComponent from 'react-native-my-library';` without curvy braces around your component name. If it does not work then it means that your linking is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, for response. Let me try